# Is it possible to convert a Debian package to an Arch Linux package?

Tags: linux, debian, arch-linux, conversion, packages

I have download Debian package from here
[Max Auto Clicker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxautoclicker/) and I get this package file `maxautoclicker_1.1_amd64.deb`.

I would like to convert it to an Arch Linux package: `.pkg.tar.zst`; is this possible?

There is an Arch Linux tool called [Alien](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/alien_package_converter/) that converts only `.deb` to `.rpm` (RedHat Linux) not to a Arch Linux package.

Comment: Look.. I am not an expert on Arch Linux.. (so you wonder WHY ARE YOU TALKING??).. ?? .. Well I AM an expert on producing packages for Linux in general.  Converting .deb to .rpm never quite works out like one would like.  The systems are different.  I am guessing that the .zst format is not different.  Decompress your debian package.. and figure out (by hand) how to convert this to ArchLinux.. also question (yourself) why you picked a flavor of Linux that came up with (YET ANOTHER) package manager when this was already cooked three times over (zypper,rpm,deb,???).

Comment: It predates zypper, for one...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [`debtap`](https://github.com/helixarch/debtap) which is a tool that converts `.deb` packages into Arch Linux packages.

Usage seems to be quite simple:

```
debtap [options] package_filename For example: debtap world-of-goo-demo_1.0_i386.deb
```

As are the options:

```
-h  --help        Prints help
-u  --update      Update debtap database
-q  --quiet       Bypass all questions, except for editing metadata file(s)
-Q  --Quiet       Bypass all questions (not recommended)
-s  --pseudo      Create a pseudo-64-bit package from a 32-bit .deb package
-w  --wipeout     Wipeout versions from all dependencies, conflicts etc.
-p  --pkgbuild    Additionally generate a PKGBUILD file
-P  --Pkgbuild    Generate a PKGBUILD file only
-v  --version     Print version
```

But as the author of this tool states, it might not work:

> “Debtap cannot be 100% accurate for several reasons, the main reason for this is the complexity of packages names. If you want to check the freshly generated `.PKGINFO` and `.INSTALL` (this is optional file) metadata files or even fix the untranslated packages names inside `.PKGINFO`, debtap offers you the option to edit these files before compressing the final package.”

While Linux packages are generally very inherently portable, you never know what kind of oddball bistro specific nonsense might muck up the works when one does a conversion like this.

So hope this works! But keep the author’s very clear and honest caveats in mind when using this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try is alternate tools available on Arch Linux

### xautoclick

---

Github - [xautoclick-github](https://github.com/qarkai/xautoclick)

AUR - [packages-xautoclick](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xautoclick/)

Preview

[image]

Missing feature - [No option from to right click](https://github.com/qarkai/xautoclick/issues/10)

### xdotool

---

To get point coordinates where you want to click

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

Create a `script`

```
gedit script
```

Paste the following on gedit (change the XXX and YYY for the numbers you got before)

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
  xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1 &
  sleep 5
done
```

> Left mouse is 1, middle is 2, right is 3, wheel up is 4, wheel down is
> 5

Save and close it

```
chmod +x script
```

To execute it

```
./script
```

Comment: This is completely out of topic. The question is how to convert `.deb` into `.pkg`, not an alternative to "Max Auto Clicker" for Arch Linux. OP can open another thread if he wants such an alternative.